# match against doesn't work with the word "when"

Tags: mysql, sql

When `desc` contains the string: `zoom when wifi dies for 1 second`

Query 1:

```
SELECT * FROM `pics` WHERE MATCH(title, desc, owntags, usertags) AGAINST('+zoom* +wifi*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

No problem, I get the row!

Query 2:

```
SELECT * FROM `pics` WHERE MATCH(title, desc, owntags, usertags) AGAINST('+zoom* +when*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

No results! So `when` belongs to sql commands.

So how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to learn some basics about full text search.  One very important concept are [stop words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-stopwords.html).  These are words that are not included in the full-text index, because they are so common or add little meaning (at least from the perspective of the person who created the stop word list . . . a famous problem involves the band The Who).

The word `'when'` is a common stop word and a default stop word in MySQL (see [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-stopwords.html#fulltext-stopwords-stopwords-for-myisam-search-indexes) and [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-stopwords.html#fulltext-stopwords-stopwords-for-innodb-search-indexes)).  So, it is not being indexed.

You will need to recreate your full text indexes, either removing all stop words or using your own custom list.

Comment: @EduardUnruh . . . You probably also want to be aware of minimum word length as well.

Comment: Yeah it's 3 when wildcard is used, otherwise 4